# I do not get RESPONSE data from Java Servlet using FETCH API

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, fetch-api

I want to POST data using FETCH API and get the RESPONSE in JSON format. Front end: JavaScript, backend Java Servlet and PostgreSQL. My problem is I do not get a response from Servlet. I do not see JSON format data in browser console.

JavaScript Code

```
let button = document.getElementById("inputSubmit");

button.addEventListener("click", postData);


function postData(){

fetch("http://localhost:8080/StudentRegisterApplication/register", {
    method : "POST",
    headers : {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body : JSON.stringify({
        username : "Jack"
    })
}).then(function(response) {
 return response.json();
}).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

}

Java Servlet Code

```
    public static void getAllStudents(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    resp.setContentType("application/json");        
    
    List<Student> students = studentService.getAllStudents();
    
    PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
    
    String json = om.writeValueAsString(students);
    System.out.println(json);
    
    pw.write(json);
    
}
```

//When I print string "json", I print all students in json format in Java Console but pw.write(json) is a response for fetch api ??? I do not see these data in my browser ?? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your browser console showing any error ?Also ,why you are printing same `json` two times ? remove `System.out.println(json);` .

Comment: It did not work :(

Comment: Are you seeing any error in browser consle ?